# How to do critical system updates through the Command Line under Kubuntu 10.10

Tags: updates, kubuntu, aptitude

I really need to do some system updates because sometimes my S.O Kubuntu 10.10 fails to start, crash down or keeps freezing after I log in.

The problem is, I cannot use  KPackageKit because it offers updates for the packages of every application instaled on my computer and I just want to do kernel related updates because my internet connection is to slow and unnestable and I think the downloading would take an eternity in case it doesn't fail.

How could I do that kind of updates using the Aptitude or something like that?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Another solution would be to limit your chosen repos to the main ones ie the security ones via your package manager or put a # to comment out all but the ones you wish to leave. Here is how I would have done it when I used to use Kubunty

In konsole in kubuntu type

sudo kate /etc/apt/sources.list

Then insert a # in front of all but the security releases
Hit save
Close 
Then run:

sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade

Hope that helps.

Let us know if you get stuck

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to apply every update KPackageKit comes up with.  You can check off the ones you require selectively.

You can also use Synaptic, which will list packages and you can pick them off as required.

Comment: thanks Duck. I already know that. But KPackageKit  lists 400 updates and I don't know which of them are really important. I know that the software update manager in Ubuntu  allows filtering those results in order to choose only the important ones. I thought doing something like that was possible through the command line via Aptitude... I don't know what to do.

Comment: @Vladimir - This probably going to get bounced to superuser or serverfault.  Chances are good someone there will be able to help.

Comment: I will take that in mind for the next time. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The "important" updates in the Ubuntu update manager are *security* updates, I believe. They won't necessarily improve your systems stability. If you don't know what program is crashing, then you cannot easily decide which updates should be installed. Of course, kernel updates are always a good bet. You'll need to select your updates manually, though, if you don't want to just install all of them.

Note that if your network connection is severed during the download process, when you restart the updates, the download will resume from where it left off. So you don't need to download everything at once for it to work.

Answer (score 0):

For packages that are already installed, you can use `sudo apt-get install $packagename` to force upgrade of *just* that package.